# how to save an image column in MSSQL to file system?

Tags: sql-server, query

Imagine I have a table like this in MSSQL

```
-------------------------------------
file_name(varchar) | file_doc(image) |
--------------------------------------
A                  | image_binary1   |
--------------------------------------
B                  | image_binary2   |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to save contents of this table to file system something like the following

```
 
 - c:\somewhere\A.pdf 
 - c:\somewhere\B.pdf
```

how to achive that in MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The easiest way is to use `SSIS`: the `Export Column` component does
   what you are looking for. Here is an example: [Export images from a
   SQL Server Table to a Folder with SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2693/export-images-from-a-sql-server-table-to-a-folder-with-ssis/)

   This is not only the easiest way, it requires minimal permissions:
   only `SELECT` permission on the table and access to file folder.
2. Also you can write a `powershell` script: [Export SQL Server BLOB
   Data with PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx)

   The user should be able not only access a table (`SELECT`
   permission) but the rights to execute `powershell` scripts.
3. It can be done using `bcp` but only for 1 file at a time, so for
   multiple files you need to write a cursor and use `xp_cmdshell`. Use of
   `xp_cmdshell` is not a best practice, it should be enabled on your
   server and you should have elevated permissions to be able to use
   `xp_cmdshell`.
   In case of `bcp` you should use `format file`, otherwise your files will contain additional 8 bytes and have a wrong format.